# What alternatives to the Rwandan option does the UK have for handling requests for asylum and how do they compare?

Tags: united-kingdom, asylum

Following on from [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/72662/why-doesn-t-the-uk-allow-asylum-applications-to-be-made-from-overseas), I am curious to know what sorts of options might exist for national policies on handling asylum claims, and what the pros and cons of each might be, in terms of:

- Cost-effectiveness - how much does it cost to resettle one asylum seeker, on average? Please provide citations for claims relating to the costs of resettlement.
- Compatibility with UK and international law - e.g. [UK human rights law](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1998/42/schedule/1/part/I) and any relevant treaty obligations. Is there any existing case law that applies? If so please cite it. Are there any statutes that need to be considered? If so then please cite them.

I can think of a few options myself but I lack the knowledge to evaluate them:

- The status quo - allow asylum seekers to remain in the UK while their application is processed, providing housing, education, healthcare and financial support, but not allowing them to work.
- The current UK proposals: deport the less vulnerable to Rwanda to claim asylum there instead
- The Australian option: hold asylum seekers in detention centres, sometimes offshore, while their claims are processed
- Open borders - encourage and support asylum seekers to find jobs to support themselves

How do all these stack up? What other options are there?

Comment: Isn't the current proposal substantially like Australia's Christmas Island setup?  i.e. the asylum requesters are sent to Rwanda and will be processed - with all due diligence and goodwill, of course - for admittance to the UK from there?  Hard to really tell, even detailed articles segue right away on how it's not a good idea without necessarily stating what the process is.

Comment: Good question, but it would also benefit to linking to some background such as Patel's claim that critics have no alternatives *“We are taking bold and innovative steps and it’s surprising that those institutions that criticise the plans fail to offer their own solutions.”* to give some context as to why it is being asked.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica No, the UK-Rwanda Scheme is very different, although many people don't seem to realise this. The proposed mechanism is: 1)individual arrives in UK and is detained by British authorities, who decide they should be sent to Rwanda; 2)individual is transported to Rwanda; 3) individual may apply for asylum *in Rwanda* if they wish. i.e. People transported under this scheme have no prospect of receiving asylum in the UK (unless, perhaps, they manage to get to the UK *again*).

Comment: I don't understand option 4. 'Open borders' is typically taken to mean anyone can come in and stay. If that is the case, 'asylum seeker' no longer makes sense as they do not have to seek asylum but can just stay. They would more likely immediately receive refugee status at which point they are encouraged to find jobs to support themselves. There is also a lot of in-between between options 1 and 4, nothing of which requiring the Rwanda or Australian options.

Comment: Labour 2019 [Outline](https://www.ein.org.uk/news/labour-manifesto-promises-end-hostile-environment-and-establish-humane-immigration-system). Lib Dem [2019](https://www.libdems.org.uk/plan-immigration), SNP [2019](https://www.snp.org/policies/pb-what-is-the-snp-s-policy-on-immigration/) The main issue with Patel's claim is it is not the job of the opposition(s) to propose government policy. If she wants someone else to make policy, then the best way to do that is to get out of government.

Comment: Please could those responsible for repeatedly refusing to re-open this question make some constructive suggestions as to what might make this question sufficiently non-opinion-based? I would have thought that questions of cost and legality could be settled fairly objectively via citations.

Comment: There have to be 100 different options actually in use globally which one would you like critiqued? This question, like Patel's, is asking us to invent policy for the UK government. That's not the site's purpose.

Comment: I don't know what all of those options are - I'm interested in hearing about any of them you happen to know about. The alternatives listed in the opposition manifestos you linked seem particularly apposite. I would definitely accept an answer that covered some of those.